# What is MvxCachingFragmentActivity superseded by?

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to update an application (inherited, I didn't write it) written with MvvmCross 4.4 to 5.7, and I see that MvxCachingFragmentActivity no longer exists. What is meant to replace this functionality?

I tried changing it to an MvxFragmentActivity, but it appears that is missing the existing overrides for things like CloseFragment, OnFragmentChanging, OnFragmentChanged, etc. which appear to be on the Presenter now.

What is my path forward for replicating the behavior of this activity in the new framework? How can I update this without affecting the caching of fragments or the existing overrides in the MvxFragmentActivity?

Comment: I have no clue what you're working with but a quick google search led me to this `No dependency on MvxCachingFragmentActivity. All Activities can show Fragments now` So I assume it's no longer required? https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-52-release/

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no migration guide, especially since you are upgrading to 5.7 and not the latest MVVMCross version. What you could do is to look for what new overrides are available and use those instead. I would recommend upgrading to the latest version 6.3.1 and use the examples on Github to figure out what you need to set up an MVVMCross solution now.

Comment: @Saamer, I started going to 6.3.1, but as there were so many breaking changes between 4.4 and 6.3.1, it was getting dangerously close to rewriting the whole product in one changeset, so I'm trying to take a staged approach 4.4->5.7->6.3.1